# GIDSignIn adding calendar scope not working

Tags: ios, scope, calendar, google-signin, gidsignin

Seems like I am following instructions given by google, but when permissions screen appears all I see is the basic profile view permission.
Previously was using GPPSignInButton and it was working.
Below is the code used

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
   NSArray *currentScopes = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes;
   signIn.scopes = [currentScopes arrayByAddingObject:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"];
   [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently changing scope inside signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController is too late. Given that I was doing this on its own view and not during application sign in/start up, this was not working. Moved scope change to viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear fixed the problem.